# Socket.io in production returns 400 Bad Request error

Tags: socket.io

I am using Socket.IO in my application. The React client uses [socket.io-client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io-client) 4.1.3, and the Node.js server uses [socket.io](https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io) 4.1.3

In the development environment on my local machine, everything works fine.

The React app runs on http://localhost:3000, and connects to the server using:

```js
import io from 'socket.io-client';
const socket = io('http://localhost:5000/');
```

The Node.js server is configured as below:

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const server = require('http').createServer(app);
const cors = require('cors');
const io = require('socket.io')(server, {
    cors: {
        origin: 'http://localhost:3000'
    },
    maxHttpBufferSize: '1e6'
});
app.set('io', io);
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(express.json({ limit: '7mb' }));
app.use(cors({ origin: 'http://localhost:3000' }));
server.listen(5000, () => console.log('Server started'));
```

In production, I am using Firebase to host the React app, in a subdirectory (e.g. https://www.example.com/app/).

In production, http://localhost:5000/ and http://localhost:3000 in the code above have also been changed to https://app.example.com and https://www.example.com/app respectively.

My server uses Ubuntu 20.04, Nginx, and Let's Encrypt, with a server block set up as follows:

```
server {

    server_name app.example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5000/;
    }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/app.example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/app.example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}server {
    if ($host = app.example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name app.example.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

In Google Chrome, I was getting *No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource* as an error. Changing the origin from https://www.example.com/app to * in the Node.js code fixed this.

However, now I am getting the following error in my browser:

*POST https://app.example.com/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=NirW_WK&sid=PmhwTyHRXOV4jWOdAAAF 400 (Bad Request)*

Why would this be?

Thanks

Comment: Can you please enable logs in nginx and paste the error that you see there?

Comment: Also, what is the response body for the 400 error?

Comment: 1. what happens when u remove the cors policy
2. can you try with webscoket rather and http ie. ws://domainname
3. in production can we connect with localhost ?

Comment: I have seen an uptick in 400 bad request errors when using let's encrypt. I believe it's a mismatch between plain HTTP requests being made to an endpoint expecting HTTPS encrypted traffic. I'm not 100% sure that is the issue, but maybe there's a lead for you there, I'd try by first removing the second `server` section managed by certbot, and wipe cache for the redirect 301 from that block to the HTTPS block.

Answer (score 0):

A few small changes to both the Node.js and Nginx should resolve your problem:

#### Node.js

First off, I'd recommend that you change this:

```js
cors: {
  origin: 'http://localhost:3000'
},
```

to this (as specified [here](https://socket.io/docs/v3/handling-cors/)):

```js
cors: {
  origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
  methods: ["GET", "POST"]
},
```

---

#### Nginx

Change this:

```
location / {
  proxy_pass http://localhost:5000/;
}
```

to this:

```
location / {
  add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
  add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
  add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
  proxy_pass http://localhost:5000/;
}
```

[This post](https://serverfault.com/a/716283) here can help give more information on CORS headers needed in Nginx reverse proxies

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a variable port to access an environment variable. PORT should be set to https://app.example.com/

```
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000
```

And use it everywhere that local host 3000 was used in your backend code.

This should also help

```
const io = require("socket.io")(server, {
cors: {

origin: port,
methods: ["GET", "POST"],
allowedHeaders: ['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'],
credentials: false
```

}
})

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue and backend was on aws elasticbeanstalk, so we set Load Balancer, to handle multiple request calls and this error was fixed. So i think you need to check cloud base function for load balancing.

Comment: Can you be more explicit about your solution? I've issue with EBS and Load Balancer, I can't figure out ! Thanks